# Why are some SVG-images not visible in my footer?

Tags: images, footer, svg

On our website, we have a footer (built with WP-Bakery) that includes the typical information that is needed, plus there is a section that should show the different types of payment methods that we accept. But for an unknown reason, some of these SVG-Images (not even every time the same) are not visible. Looking at the page, e.g. with Chrome inspector, I can see the images are all there, but they don't show.
We tried different types of SVG-Images, for example the normal SVG or the optimized SVG. We tried to add a width and height to the pictures in the HTML text, and we exchanged the SVG to different SVG pictures to check if the files have any errors. It's still not working, and maybe you know what we should do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've already done this, so forgive me if I'm telling you something you already know.

But WordPress doesn't support SVG Uploads out of the box, so to speak. This is due to security issues that can be created when a user uploads SVGs with malicious code. Mainly, a problem if you let random visitors upload SVGs.

Sometimes builders like WP-Bakery or Elementor will let you upload them, but it always seems to be buggy.

I'd suggest installing something like [SVG Support](https://wordpress.org/plugins/svg-support/)

It should work out of the box. If not play around with settings like "Inline SVG" if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but I already have that plugin installed and using inline pretty much destroys the site.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was doing it by hand using the following piece of HTML:

```
<img class="style-svg" alt="alt-text" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/PATH/TO/SVG/my_svg.svg"/>
```